# Can't get in macOS Utilities

Tags: macos, mojave, downgrade

I'm having a problem when I try to get into macOS Utilities. When I hold CMD + R it shows me a prohibited symbol. I'm trying to downgrade my MacBook because its running very slow. Currently I have Mojave installed and I want to donwgrade it to High Sierra.
Before I installed Mojave everything was fine. I could go to the utilities without any problem. it happened after I installed it and can't access the utilities.

About my Mac:
**macOS** Mojave Version 10.14.6
**Macbook** (13-inch, Aluminum, Late 2008)
**Processor** 2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
**Memory** 4 GB 1067 Mhz DDR3
**Graphics** NVIDIA GeForce 9400M 256 MB

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't have a recovery volume.  Post the result of a 'diskutil list'.

Comment: Mojave does not support the 2008 MacBook. How did you install it? The latest OS that supports your Mac is 10.11 El Capitan.

Comment: I followed a dosdude1 tutorial on how to install Mojave on unsupported Mac.

diskutil list:
 #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS oofiegang               239.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

Comment: I wouldn't mind installing El Capitan if that makes it easier.

Comment: Have you tried booting into Internet Recovery using Command+Option+R? Also, you can usually access your old downloads of OS's from the App Store listed with your previously purchased apps.

Answer (score 3):

Since Mojave isn't officially supported the recovery partition might be missing.

An alternate way to access the utilities without the CMD+R is to create an install usb. To do this first pick which version you want.

1. Download image. Downloads can be found at [this apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683)
2. Find a 16GB usb flash drive to put the image on (back up all data from it because it will be erased).
3. Create the usb. You can find the right commands [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).
4. Boot off of the usb by holding down option when pressing the power button.
5. Access any utilities needed.